# How can I count the total number of duplicate values between 2 tables on an inner join

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query

```
    SELECT fixtures.Fixture_ID, fixtures.Home_Score,
 fixtures.Away_Score, predict.Fixture_ID, predict.pHome_Score, predict.pAway_Score 

    FROM fixtures INNER JOIN predict 
ON fixtures.Fixture_ID=predict.Fixture_ID
```

I want to count the number of times the following condition is met

```
 fixtures.Home_Score=predict.pHome_Score 
AND fixtures.Away_Score=predict.pAway_Score 
AND fixtures.Fixture_ID=predict.Fixture_ID
```

I tried using a 'COUNT(*)' then 'Having count(*)>1' but cant get the syntax to work

I have also tried to count the number of times the if condition is met in the following php. I'm not sure if this is possible, so I thought the count might have to done within as SQL statement

```
<?php


     $current = $user->data()->id;



                        $sql2 = "SELECT fixtures.Home_team, fixtures.Away_Team, fixtures.Home_Score, fixtures.Away_Score, predict.pHome_Score, predict.pAway_Score FROM fixtures 
INNER JOIN predict 
ON fixtures.Fixture_ID=predict.Fixture_ID WHERE predict.id='".$current."'";                 

    echo "The number of detected predictions:", '<br>';

                        $predictions = DB::getInstance()->query($sql2);

                            foreach ($predictions->results() as $rows) {
                            $rows= get_object_vars($rows);
                             $num_rows= $predictions->count();
                            }

                         for($count=0;$count<$num_rows;$count++){


                            $r_home_score = $predictions->results()[$count]->Home_Score;
                            $p_home_score = $predictions->results()[$count]->pHome_Score;
                            $r_away_score = $predictions->results()[$count]->Away_Score;
                            $p_away_score = $predictions->results()[$count]->pAway_Score;

                             $p=0;

                                if($r_home_score==$p_home_score&&$r_away_score==$p_away_score){


                                    $p++;

                                    echo $p;


                                    }


                            }
```

The output is:

The number of detected predictions:
111111

I want to output 6

Comment: `select count(*) from ... ` plus the join clauses you already have. that's pretty much it.

Comment: You have to pass a paramter to COUNT. You can use `*` or a field name, i think `*` is prefered.

Comment: @MarcB, without grouping, count(*) will return 1 for each row, doesn't it? The way the question is written, it asks for analytical functions, but those don't exist in MySQL. But maybe if Kevin gives a bit more details (example data + desired outcome), we can find a good solution.

Comment: @GolezTrol, I've tried using php to count the number of duplicates from an if conditional statement. If you want to check out my edited question, I've included the php code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a single count returned from the database, you could just do a query like this:

```sql
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS mycount
    FROM fixtures f 
    JOIN predict p
      ON p.Fixture_ID  = f.Fixture_ID
     AND p.pHome_Score = f.Home_Score
     AND p.pAway_Score = f.Away_Score
```

---

**FOLLOWUP**

```
  $dbh = DB::getInstance();
  $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS mycount
            FROM fixtures f 
            JOIN predict p
              ON p.Fixture_ID  = f.Fixture_ID
             AND p.pHome_Score = f.Home_Score
             AND p.pAway_Score = f.Away_Score
           WHERE p.id = ?"; 
  if ($sth = $dbh->prepare($sql)) {
      $sth->bindParam(1, $current, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      if ($sth->execute()) {
          if ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

              echo $row['mycount'];

          } else {
              // this should never happen with a COUNT(*) query
              echo "query returned 0 rows";
          }
      } else {
          echo "PDO error on execute: ";
          print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
  } else {
      echo "PDO error on prepare: ";
      print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
  }
```

Comment: The result is 1000 more than I needed but i can just subtract the 1000 to give me the correct result. Thank you so much you saved my bacon. :)

Comment: You shouldn't have to be subtracting 1000. I notice that the query in the PHP code includes a `WHERE predict.id = val`. You could add a similar `WHERE` clause to the query in this answer... `WHERE p.id = val`.

Comment: I tried this: $sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS mycount FROM fixtures f JOIN predict p ON p.Fixture_ID = f.Fixture_ID AND p.pHome_Score = f.Home_Score AND p.pAway_Score = f.Away_Score WHERE p.id='".$current."'";

Comment: var_dump($pedictions) gives me this result object(DB)#3 (5) { ["_pdo":"DB":private]=> object(PDO)#4 (0) { } ["_query":"DB":private]=> object(PDOStatement)#7 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(169) "SELECT COUNT(*) AS mycount FROM fixtures f JOIN predict p ON p.Fixture_ID = f.Fixture_ID AND p.pHome_Score = f.Home_Score AND p.pAway_Score = f.Away_Score WHERE p.id='3'" } ["_error":"DB":private]=> bool(false) ["_results":"DB":private]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#5 (1) { ["mycount"]=> string(3) "335" } } ["_count":"DB":private]=> int(1) }

Comment: @KevinO'Hagan: It looks like it returned a value of **`355`**. PDO is returning a resultset object. You'd need to fetch the row from that, just like your original code was doing. My preference is to use **prepared statements** with **bind placeholders**. Answer updated with example code.

Comment: @ spencer7593: I tried your prepared statement but it get this error:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) - Maybe I am missing a closing brace? Can you please help me fix it?